# looking for a past version of AMSFonts

Tags: amsfonts

I am an AMSFonts user.

In order to be able to process archived documents (dated early 1990's) prepared with AMS-TeX and AMS-LaTeX, I have been keeping a very old TeX distribution (PCTeX v3.14 for DOS) which requires bitmap (pk) fonts from AMSFonts v2.1 to work.

Recently when I invoke the program again, it is found that some of the .pk files are corrupted. I tried to restore them from the original floppy diskettes, but unfortunately one of the diskettes failed too, and many files in the "DPI448" & "DPI259" directories remain broken.

I would like to ask if it is still possible to obtain a copy of AMSFonts v2.1 ?

Comment: Based on recent ams documentation the PK fonts are supposed to be built  as required but those dpi are different to the ones built in my tests (600 &720) using pctexv6 windows (demo) which still uses those old ams 2002 fonts

Comment: is it now working as I was able to find old ams packages but without pk files

Comment: Not yet. The official AMSFonts v.3 seems to contain the .mf sources. Could you tell how to generate the .pk fonts using tools from other distributions (e.g. MiKTeX or TeXLive) ?

Comment: I ran the pktex windows demo to see if it built any pk files. Which it did in my PCTeXv6setup12111\texmf-dist\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\cm folder you could try running a tex and see if it builds fresh .pk's also I found 10 year old 2008 amsfonts package at ctan history archives any older and you need to download the full iso